# replace indentation tabs with fixed number of spaces per tab

Tags: text-processing, text-formatting

Is it possible to replace only "leading tabs" with a set number of spaces per tab? I'm defining a leading tab as one that is only preceded by tabs or spaces. I'm defining a leading or an indentation tab as one that is only preceded by whitespace.

I have the following line in my `.nexrc`, cribbed from [this one](https://gopherproxy.meulie.net/sdf.org/0/users/jstg/texts/nexrc). It runs the lines between the lines containing the mark `a` and the mark `b` through a filter. that replaces tabs.

```
map \2 'a!'b pr -te2
```

However, it replaces non-leading tabs with two spaces well, which is not ideal since a literal tab is sometimes needed.

Is there an easy and portable way to replace leading tabs only with a set number of spaces per tab?

The following perl script (which could be collapsed to a one-liner) does the job of replacing leading tabs with a width supplied on the command line, but it relies on the availability of Perl and takes quadratic time (if the file consists of nothing but tabs).

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my ($width) = @ARGV;
$width //= 2;
my $replacement = ' ' x $width;

while (<>) {
    while (s/^(\s*)\t/$1$replacement/g) { }
    print;
}
```

Here's an example of what I want to happen. `^I` refers to a tab byte and `#` is a zero-width marker for the start of a line. The line below is a byte-ruler.

BEFORE:

```
#^I^I ^Ia^Ib
# 1 23 45 67
```

AFTER (tab width of 2)

```
#       a^Ib
#12345678 90
```

AFTER (tab width of 4)

```
#             a^Ib
#12345678901234 56
```

Comment: Are you looking for an nvi solution, or a general command-line solution?

Comment: `expand` (from GNU coreutils) would seem to be the obvious generic solution e.g. `expand -it3` to replace each initial tab with 3 spaces

Comment: sed 's/^\t\t*/  /' replace leading tabs with 2 spaces

Comment: sorry, I meant replacing leading tabs with two spaces per tab.

Comment: @GregoryNisbet If you want i read it add @ before my name. You can try sed ':A;s/\(^\t\)\(\t*\)/\2  /;tA'

Comment: @steeldriver `expand` expands all tabs. Using `-i` would mean using a non-portable option (only `-t` is standard).  That's _strictly speaking_, one could obviously assume that GNU coreutils was installed, but since they are concerned that Perl might not be available they would be equally concerned about GNU coreutils being available.

Comment: @Sparhawk ... a general command-line solution. I am almost positive that `nvi` is not capable of doing this. I can write commands to a line, copy them into a register and execute them, but I don't think I can loop in `nvi`.

Comment: @GregoryNisbet: Did you test out my answer? did it help?

Comment: @Inian, I did just now, it replaces any number of leading tabs with the same total number of spaces instead of the same number of spaces per tab. I don't think this can be done in awk without looping over the line multiple times.

Comment: @GregoryNisbet: Are you referring a case if there are 2 leading tabs, then 2 leading spaces need to be added? If this is the case, then the fix would involve a slight modification of the answer below

Comment: @Inian. Yes, I am. Is that achievable without looping?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for a generic solution using other command-line tools, one could use `Awk` for this.

```
var=$'\t\t\tnewcontent'
echo "$var" | awk '{ gsub(/^[\t]+/," ",$0) }1'
```

The command above replaces one more more occurrences of <kbd>Tab</kbd> with a single space i.e. 2<sup>nd</sup> argument in `gsub`. You can make it configurable though by generating how many spaces you want

```
awk -v n=5 ' BEGIN{ spaces = sprintf("%"n"s"," ") }{ gsub(/^[\t]+/,spaces,$0) }1'
```

From the last update, it seems OP wants to replace the number of leading tabs with the exact number of spaces found,

```
awk -F$'\t' '{ spaces = sprintf("%"(NF-1)"s"," "); gsub(/^[\t]+/,spaces,$0) }1'
```

The logic is with setting field separator to `\t`, the number of leading tabs can be identified by doing `NF-1`. With the number of leading tabs identified, use it to generate the same of number of spaces from earlier `sprintf()` method.

You can see it by verifying the `hexdump -C` before and after the replacement

```
echo "$var" | hexdump -C
00000000  09 09 09 6e 65 77 63 6f  6e 74 65 6e 74 0a        |...newcontent.|
0000000e
```

now with the replacement

```
echo "$var" | awk -F$'\t' '{ spaces = sprintf("%"(NF-1)"s"," "); gsub(/^[\t]+/,spaces,$0) }1' | hexdump -C
00000000  20 20 20 6e 65 77 63 6f  6e 74 65 6e 74 0a        |   newcontent.|
0000000e
```